# Update cell values of specific columns based on condition of column value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following df.... In the event where `['Catalogue']=='Equity'`, I would like to copy all data in columns ['Catalogue','Display','Shelves','Price','Mechanic']` in the ['Week'] for which the condition is triggered.

In the example below,['Catalogue']=='Equity' occurs in ['Week']== '1' so in this situation, I would like to copy data that occurs in ['Catalogue','Display','Shelves','Price','Mechanic']`which happens to be 'Equity','Tactical,0.0,NaN,0.5 for all rows where ['Week']== '1'` ).

I would then like to do a calculation in `['Price']` of `['Mechanic']*['RRP']`

Sample Dataset is below

```
   Product Name  Year   Customer  Week   RRP Catalogue   Display  Shelves  Price Mechanic
0      product1  2016  Customer1     1  6.99    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0    NaN      0.5
1      product2  2016  Customer1     1  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
2      product3  2016  Customer1     1  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
3      product1  2016  Customer1     2  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
4      product2  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
5      product3  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
6      product1  2016  Customer1     3  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
7      product2  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
8      product3  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
9      product1  2016  Customer1     4  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
10     product2  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
11     product3  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
12     product1  2016  Customer1     5  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
13     product2  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
14     product3  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
```

My desired output is below...

```
   Product Name  Year   Customer  Week   RRP Catalogue   Display  Shelves  Price Mechanic
0      product1  2016  Customer1     1  6.99    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   3.50      0.5
1      product2  2016  Customer1     1  3.49    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   1.74      0.5
2      product3  2016  Customer1     1  3.49    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   1.74      0.5
3      product1  2016  Customer1     2  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
4      product2  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
5      product3  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
6      product1  2016  Customer1     3  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
7      product2  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
8      product3  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
9      product1  2016  Customer1     4  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
10     product2  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
11     product3  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
12     product1  2016  Customer1     5  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
13     product2  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
14     product3  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: PLEASE do not post screenshots of code and data. We cannot copy the if necessary.

Comment: Please be specific: override the week with what?

Comment: @Luca Cappelletti I have updated to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: sorry for posting images (!) I'll no longer do that going forward

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cols = ['Catalogue','Display','Shelves','Price','Mechanic']

m1 = df['Catalogue']=='EQUITY'
#boolean mask for all Weeks contains at least one EQUITY in column Catalogue
m2 = df['Week'].isin(df.loc[m1, 'Week'])

#filter df and for week forward and then back filling missing values
df[m2] = df[m2].groupby('Week').ffill().groupby('Week').bfill()
#convert column to numeric
mech = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[m2, 'Mechanic'], errors='coerce')
#multiple filtered columns
df.loc[m2, 'Price'] = (df.loc[m2, 'RRP'] * mech).round(2)

#for temporary display for disable representation of dataframes to stretch across pages
with pd.option_context('display.expand_frame_repr', False):
    print (df)

   Product Name  Year   Customer  Week   RRP Catalogue   Display  Shelves  Price Mechanic
0      product1  2016  Customer1     1  6.99    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   3.50      0.5
1      product2  2016  Customer1     1  3.49    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   1.74      0.5
2      product3  2016  Customer1     1  3.49    EQUITY  Tactical      0.0   1.74      0.5
3      product1  2016  Customer1     2  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
4      product2  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
5      product3  2016  Customer1     2  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
6      product1  2016  Customer1     3  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
7      product2  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
8      product3  2016  Customer1     3  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
9      product1  2016  Customer1     4  6.99       NaN     Shelf      NaN   2.44  3 for 2
10     product2  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   3.28  3 for 2
11     product3  2016  Customer1     4  3.49       NaN     Shelf      NaN   1.97  3 for 2
12     product1  2016  Customer1     5  6.99       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
13     product2  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
14     product3  2016  Customer1     5  3.49       NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me the required output as it doesnt fill out the information in the same corresponding week  - also,why have you explicitly called out the cols at the top?